# Metric Space VS Normed Space VS Inner Product Space

Tags: general-topology

I am taking my first course in topology and the lecturer briefly mentioned those $3$ spaces: 1.Metric Space 2. Normed Space 3. Inner Product Space

For better understanding, I was wonder, how are those 3 connected? for example I know that $||x||=\sqrt{<x,x>}$ so the norm is a "subset" or there are inner products that induce a norm? and a metric space is a "subset" of norm space?

Answer (score 4):

The three types of spaces imply increasingly greater assumptions of "structure":

1. In a metric space we we can talk about the distance between points, $d(x,y)$, which allows for topological concepts of open sets, etc.
2. In a normed space we can in addition talk about the size of a given point: $||x||$. Any norm $||\cdot||$ induces a metric: $d(x,y) = ||x - y||$.
3. In an inner product space we can in addition talk about the "angles" between points, and define projections (and all nice things that we do with inner products). Any inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$ induces a norm: $||x|| = \sqrt{(x,x)}$.

Answer (score 3):

Every inner product induces a norm, but not vice versa.

Every norm induces a metric, but not vice versa.

Thus you have something like $$ \left\{ \mathrm{Inner\ Product\ Spaces} \right\} \subsetneq \left\{ \mathrm{Normed\ Spaces} \right\} \subsetneq \left\{ \mathrm{Metric\ Spaces} \right\}$$

Comment: So a metric space has the most "restrictions" or axioms and inner product space is the most abstract?

Comment: @gbox it's rather the other way around: we make many more assumptions about an inner product space, so in that sense it is less abstract. The metric space is the one with the fewest assumptions of the three, so it is the most abstract.

Answer (score 1):

You have $\text{IPS} \subsetneq \text{NS} \subsetneq{MS}$.

To conclude that $\text{IPS} \subset \text{NS}$, as you write above, consider the norm $\|x\| = \sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle}$. To conclude that $\text{NS} \not\subset \text{IPS}$, consider $L^p$ for $p \neq 2$ (or any non-reflexive Banach space).

To conclude that $\text{NS} \subset \text{MS}$, consider the metric $d(x,y) = \|x - y\|$. To conclude that $\text{MS} \not\subset \text{NS}$, use any metric space which is not a vector space (metric spaces don't need to be vector spaces, but normed spaces --and inner-product spaces-- do).

Answer (score 0):

Examples in $2$-dimensional space $\mathbb R^2$:

$\bullet\quad$ $l^2$ norm: $\|(x,y)\| = (x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$  .  This space is an inner product space, a normed space, and a metric space.

$\bullet\quad$ $l^p$ norm, $1 \le p < \infty, p \ne 2$: $\|(x,y)\| = (x^p+y^p)^{1/p}$  .  This space is a normed space, and a metric space, but not an inner product space.

$\bullet\quad$ $l^p$ distance, $0 < p < 1$: $d((x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)) = (x_1-x_2)^p+(y_1-y_2)^p$  .  This space is a metric space, but not an inner product space and not a normed space.